# Markov random field vs Markov Logic Network

Tags: markov-random-fields

I am new in statistic area please could you help

Please, could anyone give me a clear difference between Markov random field and Markov Logic network?
what is the difference?

I know that MRF is an undirect type of graphical model.
but what is the difference?
please

thank you for your help